# How to change color of individual words in a text editor/ fade them out over time

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, text-editor

I am trying to create a text box that allows users to type. As they do, the most recent (last) words will be black and the previous ones fade to white.

Right now, I have a contenteditable with the following code. Whenever there is a change it takes the current text, splits it into words, wraps the last few words in a span with a black text color class and the previous ones in a span with a white text color class (and some fade between colors). It works, but doesn't allow for new lines nor any formatting (bold/italics/underline). Is there a way to do this that still allows those? I've tried looking at other customizable rich text editors like quill but couldn't figure out how to get the fade effect. I don't need most of the functionalities of these rich text editors, really only bolding/italics/maybe font size.

```
editor.setAttribute("data-placeholder", getRandomPlaceholder(placeholderTexts));


// get rid of spell check red squiggles
editor.spellcheck = false;
editor.focus();
editor.blur();

editor.addEventListener('input', () => {
    let words = editor.innerText.split(/\s+/);
    let blackWords = words.slice(-3);
    let fadeWords = words.slice(-8, -3);
    let whiteWords = words.slice(0, -8);

    let whiteSpan = document.createElement('span');
    whiteSpan.className = 'white';
    whiteSpan.innerText = whiteWords.join(' ');

    // Create fade spans
    let fadeSpans = fadeWords.map((word, index) => {
        let span = document.createElement('span');
        span.className = `fade-${index + 1}`;
        span.innerText = word;
        return span;
    });

    let blackSpan = document.createElement('span');
    blackSpan.className = 'black';
    blackSpan.innerText = blackWords.join(' ');

    editor.innerHTML = '';

    if (whiteWords.length > 0) {
        editor.appendChild(whiteSpan);
        editor.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
    }

    // Append fade spans
    fadeSpans.forEach((span, index) => {
        editor.appendChild(span);
        if (index < fadeSpans.length - 1) {
            editor.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
        }
    });

    if (fadeWords.length > 0) {
        editor.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
    }

    editor.appendChild(blackSpan);

    // Move cursor to the end
    let range = document.createRange();
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    range.selectNodeContents(editor);
    range.collapse(false);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
});
```